# Listing files in Google Drive Folder with Google API v3 JAVA

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am trying to list all files found in google drive folder, the query seems to work but when I try to get the files list using  `.getFiles()` the list is empty.

```
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/serv_acc.json";
    private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT = "xxxxxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com";

    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "ZZZ-bco-eXXX_oo";
    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE);
    private static final String ROOT_FOLDER = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";


    private static final String projection = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";
    
    private static Drive driveService;
 

public static void buildApiService() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        InputStream resourceAsStream = GoogleDriveApplication.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(
                ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(resourceAsStream).createScoped(SCOPES).createDelegated(SERVICE_ACCOUNT));
        driveService = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY,                       requestInitializer).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
    }

public static List<File> getChildren(String id) throws IOException {

        String query = "'" + id + "'" + " in parents";

        FileList directChildren = driveService.files().list()
                .setQ(query).setFields(projection).execute();

        System.out.println(directChildren.isEmpty()); // False
        System.out.println(directChildren.size()); // 3
        System.out.println(directChildren.getFiles().isEmpty()); // True
        ...
    }

public static void main(String[] args) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {

        buildApiService();
       ....
    }
```

Here is what the folder looks like :

1 subfolder, 1 zip (1,63 Go), 1 Xlsx (200Kb) !

Please note :

. Same credentials work on same folder when used by other process (code in Python)
. Same Java code works on other Folders

EDIT 2 : I coded the same thing in Python. No changes made on credentials or on Google drive Folder (Permissions, rights etc.) and it works fine.

```
# The needed import for service account credentials:
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload
from apiclient.discovery import build
from getfilelistpy import getfilelist
import io
import flatdict
import os
scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
# Parsing JSON credentials for a service account:
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('C:/serv_acc.json', scope)
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
topFolderId = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'  
resource = {
    "service_account": credentials,
    "id": topFolderId,
    "fields": "files(id,name)",
}
res = getfilelist.GetFileList(resource)
print(dict(res))
```

The service account is a part of a group of users having access to the folder which is open to External users.

Comment: What is the value of projection?

Comment: private static final String projection = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";

Comment: Have you set ServiceAccountUser ?

Comment: Yes I did ! I edited my question with the some other info.

Comment: Could you edit your post with the way you create the credentials?

Comment: Edited with credentials creation.

Comment: Could you try to read all the pages (nextPageToken)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found it.
I missed the two params :

```
   FileList directChildren = driveService.files().list()
                .setQ(query).setSupportsAllDrives(true).setIncludeItemsFromAllDrives(true).execute();
```

It looks like the deprecations have been revoked and I didn't know.

> **supportsAllDrives** : Deprecated - Whether the requesting application supports both My Drives and shared drives. This parameter
> will only be effective until June 1, 2020. Afterwards all applications
> are assumed to support shared drives. (Default: false)
>
> **includeItemsFromAllDrives**: Deprecated - Whether both My Drive and shared drive items should be included in results. This parameter will
> only be effective until June 1, 2020. Afterwards shared drive items
> will be included in the results. (Default: false)

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a `200` response with an empty list and you know that the folder has some files, then the most likely reason is that the folder is not shared with the service account.

From what I see in your code, when setting up the credentials you used `createDelegated(SERVICE_ACCOUNT)`, where `SERVICE_ACCOUNT` is just the `xxxxxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com` address of the service account that you're using. The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-auth-library/latest/com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials#com_google_auth_oauth2_ServiceAccountCredentials_createDelegated_java_lang_String_) states that if the service account has [domain-wide delegation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106) you have to specify the user that you want to impersonate (so if the folder is owned by user@yourdomain.com, you have to use that address instead):

> If the credentials support domain-wide delegation, creates a copy of the identity so that it impersonates the specified user; otherwise, returns the same instance.

So, if you've already set up domain-wide delegation for your service account you need to first impersonate the owner of the folder, or someone else who has access to it. Otherwise you need to first [share](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/7166529) the folder with your service account.

##### References:

- [Domain-wide delegation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106)
- [createDelegated() method](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-auth-library/latest/com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials#com_google_auth_oauth2_ServiceAccountCredentials_createDelegated_java_lang_String_)

Comment: The service account is a part of a group of users having access to the folder which is open to External users. Edited my post with a working python code with same configuration of credentials as well as folder permissions.

Comment: That's tricky then. What's the value of `id`that's being passed to `getChildren(String id)`? I don't see it being run. I guess another reason could be that the ID being passed is not what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

A service account is a dummy user, it has its own google drive account.  The reason its returning no files is that you have not uploaded any yet.

If you have a directory on your own personal google drive account, you can take the service account email address and share the directory with the service account.  The service account will then have access to any files within that directory.

If you have a google workspace account, you could also configure domain wide delegation and allow the service account to access anything on the workspace domain.

Comment: The service account is a part of a group of users having access to the folder which is open to External users. Edited my post with a working python code with same configuration of credentials as well as folder permissions.

Comment: Are you saying you have configured domain wide delegation on your google workspace account?

Comment: No. I don't even have the rights to do that. What I'am saying is that using same config (Credentials, permissions and rights) It work's with Python but not with java.

Comment: Mind doing a file.list with the service account for me and tell me the directory Id exists.   Also please verify that you are using exactly the same topFolderId and ROOT_FOLDER.   Your java code doesn't even appear to be calling getChildren